# R-Markdown's render_site function is deleting the contents of the .git folder

Tags: r, git, version-control, r-markdown

Im trying to version control a website generated with R-Markdown's `render_site` function by pushing it directly from the output directory, the default `_site` folder. Problem is, every time i call the `render_site` function it clears most of the content of the `.git` folder (save for the `objects` folder within) and breaks the link between the local and remote directory. Is there any way to stop this from happening? Curiously, the `clean_site` function clears the exact same folders and files from the `.git` folder so im guessing the problem is related to some post build cleanup.

The webpage directory looks something like this:

```
_site/
├── /.git
├── /index_files
├── /about_files
├── intex.html
├── about.html
└── styles.css
```

The `.git` folder before rendering the site looks like:

```
.git/
├── /hooks
├── /info
├── /logs
├── /objects
├── /refs
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── config
├── description
├── FETCH_HEAD
├── HEAD
└── index
```

And after building only the `objects` folder is left:

```
.git/
└── /objects
```

I should also note that rendering each `.Rmd` file into htmls individually does not cause the same problem.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Can you make it more clear exactly how your project is laid out?

Comment: You should put version control in the root directory of your project and not inside the sites folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `clean` function for the site generator doesn't exclude anything.  You can replace it fairly easily, using a scheme something like this:

Choose a name for your new generator, and put it in the YAML for the `index.Rmd` file, e.g.

```
site:  my_site
```

Write `my_site` to modify the default generator (or the original custom one,
if you already had one):

```
my_site <- function(...) {
  site <- rmarkdown:::default_site(...) # or bookdown::bookdown_site(...), etc.
  # Modify the clean function
  oldclean <- site$clean
  site$clean <- function(...) {
    files <- oldclean(...)
    # leave out any filename containing .git
    grep("[.]git", files, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
  }
  site
}
```

I haven't tested this and might have the pattern wrong in the new clean function, but it should be close to working.

You might also want to suggest to the `rmarkdown` authors (on their Github site) that it would be nice to have a way to mark certain files to exclude from cleaning.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to look into the default_site and render_site functions but didn't have a clear idea on what to do about it. I'm going to try something with your suggestion!